# Can I pass a URL as a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that is not giving me the result I want. JSFiddle link at the bottom.

Note: This is not my image. I grabbed it randomly from imgur.

I expect:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg" style="max-width:800px;">
```

But I get this, I believe, but I'm unable to write this in a code block while debugging, for some reason.

```
<img src="http://thisismydomain.com/https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg" style="max-width:800px;">
```

Here's my script. Please advise:

```
<div><a href="javascript:viewimage('https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg','video_aba');">Show Image</a></div>

<div id="jsdebug">jsdebug</div>
<div id="video_aba">video_aba</div>

<script>    
function viewimage(ytlink, uid) {
  var imagelink = ytlink;
  document.getElementById("jsdebug").innerHTML = imagelink;
  var uid = uid;
  if (imagelink.length == 0) {
    imageembed = "<strong>Sorry, unable to load.</strong>";
  } else {
    imageembed = "<img src=\"/" + imagelink + "\" style=\"max-width:800px\">";
  }
  document.getElementById("video_aba").innerHTML = imageembed;
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gde5630h/

Comment: JSFiddle has this odd behavior where functions that *appear* to be defined on the top level actually aren't, so they aren't global by default. (but, it would be even better to attach the listeners properly using `addEventListener`, and then you wouldn't have run into the problem in the first place)

Comment: is this static `'https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg` ?

Comment: No. It's passed by a variable via VBScript (classic ASP). When I debug via ASP what is passed, it is the correct URL.

Comment: The problem is you write link like this `imageembed = "<img src=\"/" + imagelink + "\" style=\"max-width:800px\">";` 
/ => this will prepend to your current domain url eg.if your domain is localhost it will goes http://localhost/https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg

Comment: I think that is not related with jsfiddle @CertainPerformance see my comment above

Comment: @hs-dev2MR how can I write this so it's not prepended? I'm running this on my own domain name, if that's what you mean by localhost.

Comment: write like this `imageembed = "<img src=" + imagelink + " style=\"max-width:800px\">";`

Comment: @hs-dev2MR That was it. I would have never imagined I shouldn't wrap that in quotes. Someone mentioned that I cannot use href= but have to use onclick=. But I receive no errors and this has worked for me for years with no problems. Thoughts?

Comment: No problem use what you prefer

Comment: Thanks to everyone for checking it out and responding. @hs-dev2MR how do I select your response as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is what your image link coded . It's like this `imageembed = "<img src=\"/" + imagelink + "\" style=\"max-width:800px\">";`

> / => this will prepend to your current domain url eg.if your domain is localhost it will goes localhost/https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ54n.jpg

So remove `/` from your image link

Comment: @hs-dev2MR  you can better syntax ES6 (i.e using backticks)

Answer (score 1):

Your attribution is not correct. `href` should be replaced with `onclick` event.

## "href" is not used for javascript events. It is used to link the webpages.

## javascript events are `onclick`, `onhover`, `onmouseenter`, etc.

```js
function viewimage(ytlink, uid) {
  var imagelink = ytlink;
  var uid = uid;
  if (imagelink.length == 0) {
    imageembed = "<strong>Sorry, unable to load.</strong>";
  } else {
    imageembed = `<img src="${ytlink}" style="width:800px">`;
  }
  document.getElementById("video_aba").innerHTML = imageembed;
  document.getElementById("jsdebug").innerText = imageembed;
}
```

```css
a {
color: blue;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#" onclick="viewimage('https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg','video_aba');">Show Image</a></div>

<div id="jsdebug">jsdebug</div>
<div id="video_aba">video_aba</div>
```

Comment: I'm using plain Javascript. Your response requires JQuery, right?

Comment: He is using plain JS. But I hope to add more explanation

Comment: @Astralis it's a `plain javascript`

Comment: That still gives me the wrong variable where I want this as the output: https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg but I get this http://example.com/https://i.imgur.com/MiOeWrk.jpg

Comment: While you're right that href should not be used for Javascript events, that doesn't mean it *can't* be - simply changing the href to onclick will not solve the problem

Comment: @CertainPerformance what do you meant to say ?  check out above snippet.

Comment: It mean href is also work for `javascript:functionname`

Comment: Really can you provide some link about it .. I didn't know it